# airflow CLI fails with no such table error when using CeleryExecutor

Tags: docker, docker-compose, airflow, airflow-scheduler

If I start Airflow containers with Celery Executor using puckel/docker-airflow's docker-compose-CeleryExecutor.yml, which can be found [here](https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow/blob/master/docker-compose-CeleryExecutor.yml).

Airflow CLI fails with no such table error. I guess this is because Airflow CLI tries to use local sqlite db but it is not initalized.

I confirmed back-end DB (PostgreSQL container) is initialized. How can I airflow CLI with CeleryExecutor?

## Steps to reproduce the error

- Start Airfow containers.
- Confirmed Airfow Web UI works as expected and back-end DB (PostgreSQL) is initialized.

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-CeleryExecutor.yml up
```

- Open new terminal and login to web server container
- Run airflow connections -l then got an errror.

```
> docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                          COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                             PORTS                                        NAMES
0646cff9283e        puckel/docker-airflow:1.10.9   "/entrypoint.sh work…"   23 seconds ago      Up 23 seconds                      5555/tcp, 8080/tcp, 8793/tcp                 docker-airflow_worker_1
d1469456a45a        puckel/docker-airflow:1.10.9   "/entrypoint.sh sche…"   24 seconds ago      Up 23 seconds                      5555/tcp, 8080/tcp, 8793/tcp                 docker-airflow_scheduler_1
6612c673485e        puckel/docker-airflow:1.10.9   "/entrypoint.sh webs…"   24 seconds ago      Up 24 seconds (health: starting)   5555/tcp, 8793/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp   docker-airflow_webserver_1
cffc97f915e3        puckel/docker-airflow:1.10.9   "/entrypoint.sh flow…"   24 seconds ago      Up 24 seconds                      8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5555->5555/tcp, 8793/tcp   docker-airflow_flower_1
24dde1b28a66        postgres:9.6                   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   25 seconds ago      Up 24 seconds                      5432/tcp                                     docker-airflow_postgres_1
3cd7cf974526        redis:5.0.5                    "docker-entrypoint.s…"   25 seconds ago      Up 24 seconds                      6379/tcp

> docker exec -it 6612c673485e bash
$ airflow connections -l
[2020-08-15 04:34:35,822] {{cli_action_loggers.py:107}} WARNING - Failed to log action with (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: log
[SQL: INSERT INTO log (dttm, dag_id, task_id, event, execution_date, owner, extra) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: ('2020-08-15 04:34:35.819743', None, None, 'cli_connections', None, 'airflow', '{"host_name": "6612c673485e", "full_command": "[\'/usr/local/bin/airflow\', \'connections\', \'-l\']"}')]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

## Edit

- I have initialized back-end DB in an entry point script. I have followed the same approach as this blog post. https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-deploy-apache-airflow-with-celery-on-aws-ce2518dbf631

```
ase "$1" in
  webserver)
    if [ -e "/requirements.txt" ]; then
      pip3 install --user --upgrade -r /requirements.txt
    fi

    airflow initdb
    exec airflow webserver
    ;;
```

Comment: for new installations / first time setup [`airflow initdb`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/cli-ref#initdb); for old deployments that ran into db problems [`airflow resetdb`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/cli-ref#resetdb)

Comment: have you made sure your entrypoint script is running properly ? You can debug that. You can also check docker container logs. as mentioned above you need to initialize the db.

Comment: Yes, I have initialized back end and sample DAGs are running correctly. I added about this on the description.